# random background bubbles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-process

according to a main content div i'm trying creating randomly background floating bubbles
this is my piece of code

## CSS

```
parent {

    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
}

.message {
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    z-index: -9999;
    line-height: 115px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;

    -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
    -moz-border-radius: 60px;
    border-radius: 60px;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="message">Hello world</div>
</div>
```

## JS

```
jQuery.fn.verticalMarquee = function(vertSpeed, horiSpeed) {
    this.css('float', 'left');

    vertSpeed = vertSpeed || 1;
    horiSpeed = 1/horiSpeed || 1;

    var windowH = this.parent().height(),
        thisH = this.height(),
        parentW = (this.parent().width() - this.width()) / 2,
        rand = Math.random() * 1000,
        current = this;

    this.css('margin-top', windowH + thisH);
    this.parent().css('overflow', 'hidden');

    setInterval(function() {
        current.css({
            marginTop: function(n, v) {
                return parseFloat(v) - vertSpeed;
            },
            marginLeft: function(n, v) {
                return (Math.sin(new Date().getTime() / (horiSpeed * 1000) + rand) + 1) * parentW;
            }
        });
    }, 15);

    setInterval(function() {
        if (parseFloat(current.css('margin-top')) < -thisH) {
            current.css('margin-top', windowH + thisH);
        }
    }, 250);
};

$('.message').verticalMarquee(1, 1);
```

so all works great with 1 element floating randomly

but when i  attach same function to many (.message) elements,
i would like to make them floating in background randomly so with a start and a end random point too.

someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you mean exactly, but if you need to know how you can get this function to work on all .message-divs you do like so:

```
$(document).ready( function( ) {
    $('.message').verticalMarquee( 1, 1 );
} );
```

Comment: nope :) sorry but i  know how to attach same function to all .message , but i would like to generate random starting and ending point for them , if i attach this funct to all .message (as it is now) they will float coordinatly, while i would like somenthing more random (any .message could have different start and end point, different width and height, different horizontal speed and vertical speed, different foating margins etc :))

Comment: Oh, so the Math.random( ) is the same for all elements.. Maybe you'd better add this function to one div, and start adding the bubbles in there, with a for loop.. Than the random should always be different..

Answer (score 0):

if you add something like the following

```
var message = 1;
$('.message').each(function(message) { 
    $(this).verticalMarquee(1, 1, message);
    message++
});
```

also add one more parameter

```
jQuery.fn.verticalMarquee = function(vertSpeed, horiSpeed, index)
```

and multiple 1000 with the `index`  get a different rand each time

```
rand = Math.random() * (index * 1000)
```

The result will be the following: http://jsfiddle.net/exr4N/1/

I don't know if this is what you need, but I suppose I gave you an idea. Good luck